# How to compile rust with tpidr1 as thread local register

Tags: rust, llvm, arm64, bare-metal

In bare-metal AArch64, rust generates `tpidr0` as the default register for `thread_local` calculations. For scenarios like kernel, `tpidr1` should be used instead of `tpidr0`. 
How to make rust compiler generate code to use `tpidr1` instead of the default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LLVM support a [custom attribute](https://reviews.llvm.org/D54685) `-mattr=tipdr-el[1|2|3]` to override the thread local register.

By default, `tipdr0` is used for this purpose. This can be overriden in rust by doing something like the following

```
rustc -C target-feature=tpidr-el1 --target=aarch64-unknown-none
```